# How can I configure Zenoss to send an SMS or Voice alert

Tags: sms, zenoss, voice, alert

Has anyone successfully configured Zenoss to send an SMS or Voice alert? Googling only comes up with a service called TeamTILT for Zenoss. Is this the only alternative available? Has anyone solved this without using this service? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest means is to simply send an e-mail to the provider's email-to-text gateway. Which, of course, requires a working internet connection :-).

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you want the pager field to goto someone's SMS "email" like 1235551234@vtext.com you can do the followin.

Create folder $ZENHOME/scripts/
Create the script below.
Page Command : $ZENHOME/scripts/mail.pl
File: mail.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


my $title="Alert";
my $to=$ARGV[0];


$from= 'Zenoss';
$subject=$title;


open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");


## Mail Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
## Mail Body
foreach $line ( <STDIN> ) {
    chomp( $line );
    print MAIL "$line\n";
}
close(MAIL);
```

As long as you have sendmail configured then you should be seeing pages.

Comment: The mail.pl script works great as long as you enter in "$ZENHOME/scripts/mail.pl $RECIPIENT" under Settings->Page Command. Other wise it does not pass the recipient variable to the script. Thanks for sharing the script!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to setup the dialer zenpack at one point to dial a 56K modem and deliver SMS that way, but only T-Mobile's numbers were still working for this method. We ended up running DSL over a dedicated POTS line for this purpose.

http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-5819